# Blogger Api - ClientLogin behind a proxy

Tags: c#, api, proxy, blogger

I am trying to create a console app that will automatically post something on my blog.
I 'm following step by step this guide https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet

Sample source from google can be found here:
http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/blogger/ConsoleSample.cs

I am using ClientLogin authentication but I am behind my company's proxy.
Luckily the proxy is configured in IE settings so I am using

```
IWebProxy myProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

How can I configure the requests to the Blogger Service to use `myProxy` ?
Normally I would do it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
IWebProxy myProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
request.Proxy = myProxy;
```

But now i have to alter the Blogger API's client libraries to use `myProxy` in every request
. Any ideas on how to do that?